# How to programmatically open a file of any type on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I've tried this:

```
var openedSuccessfully = AppKit.NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile(filePath);
```

It seems to work, except for those file types which have no default app associated with them.
When I try to open such a file from Finder, I get this dialog:

[image: Finder's app chooser]

Is there a way to programatically open this (or similar) app chooser window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the [`openFile:withApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openFile:withApplication:) method, setting the application to Finder. That should open the app chooser window, or the default app, as appropriate.

```
// Opens app chooser
AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile(unknownFile, withApplication: "Finder") 
// Opens default application
AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile(knownFile, withApplication: "Finder")
```

#### Xamarin.Mac Format:

```
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile(knownFile, "Finder");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```
NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(YOUR_PATH)
```